# MySql Create User script not working on Windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to create a SQL script for configuring a couple of application accounts in MySQL on a Windows machine. I'm using the current MySQL version 8. release.  I can create these accounts and grant permissions using the MySQL Workbench and the user is able to login using the workbench.  If I use the following script, the user cannot log in...

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS testuser@localhost;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'Test@user1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT INSERT, SHOW VIEW ON ehaw.MsgQueue TO testuser@localhost;
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON ehaw.userMsgQueue TO testuser@localhost;
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testuser'@localhost
```

When I try to connect using the MySQL Workbench with this account and password, I am presented with a "Cannot Connect to Database Server" error dialog.

Note that this user account will be used for "public" access through an application interface.  I am explicitly trying to limit permissions on this account to only those required.  The account needs to insert records in a specific table, select records from a specific view, and connect to the database...

Comment: *I am presented with a "Cannot Connect to Database Server" error dialog.* Investigate Error log and find what error does not allow you to connect. I think that this is the access to default database absence.

Comment: There isn't much in the error log at all, and nothing pertaining to user login.

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of it is that I did something stupid that caused me to incorrectly think I had a problem.

Having admitted this, the code sample I provided was badly done and I offer the following as a better example of least privilege management.

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS user@localhost;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$user1';
GRANT INSERT, SHOW VIEW ON schema.msgQueue TO user@localhost;
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON schema.userMsgQueue TO user@localhost;
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW on schema.eventMetadata to user@localhost;
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';
```

Lesson learned, case closed...